# Network stream error "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written"

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

The code below occasionally blows and it's because the using block exits causing a dispose on the "stream" object before the stream has been written fully.

```
private void DoStuff(Stream input) 
{
    using (var stream = _httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[input.Length];
        input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Flush();
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:
The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

Comment: Doe it only happen with large inputs? Does chunking the data help?

Comment: Not sure on the inputs ... probably fairly large as it tends to be media files.  I'm told chunking also failed but not seen that in action!

Comment: The only way the code can fail is if the server closes the connection before all the data is sent.  If you use a try/catch instead of the using you can eliminate the error, but that still doesn't explain why the connection was closed.

Comment: Chunking is probably giving a timeout because the next chunk message is not being sent.

Comment: How are you setting up `_httpWebRequest`?